# A list of all available tokens?

Tags: tokens

Is there a way to display a list of all available tokens on the system (other than scrolling through the dropdown)?

Our donor intake person would like to see what's available in a readable way.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but FYI that dropdown is searchable, so you don't have to scroll if you don't want to.